# SQL Query group by column, where other column is different

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok sample data from table Users:

```
ThisId  ThatId
1       5
1       5
1       6
2       7
3       8
3       8
4       9
```

First i get the records with duplicate ThisId, so:

```
SELECT
    ThisId
FROM
    Users
GROUP BY
    ThisId
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This works and returns

```
ThisId
1
3
```

However I only want the records where the ThatId is different. So my output should be only:

```
ThisId
1
```

Because the records with ThisId 1 have different ThatIds (5,6). And the records with ThisId 3 all have Thatid 8.

I'm pretty much stuck here and don't know how to achieve this.

I hope you understand,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below query should work

```
SELECT
    ThisId
FROM
    Users
GROUP BY
    ThisId
HAVING 
    COUNT(distinct ThatId) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer.

```
SELECT
    ThisId
FROM
    Users
GROUP BY
    ThisId
HAVING 
    MAX(ThatId) <> MIN (ThatId)
```

Result:

```
ThisId
-----------
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Really simple but would this work ?

```
SELECT
    ThisId
FROM
    Users
GROUP BY
    ThisId
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT ThatId) > 1
```